# Opening a Port tcp and telnet

Tags: windows, .net, socket

I have windows server 2008 and want to open a port say 2342 for tcp and telnet access

i have added a firewall exception create rule but when connecting to it returned "Connection Refused" error in all the following manners

1. Through .net socket server application
2. Telnet
3. Tera Terminal

Please help me out as soon as possible and let me know if this is the right place for this question... if not please forward it?

Comment: What language? Also, please provide some sample code. We can't help you if we can't see how you're attempting to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You should confirm that the server is, in fact, listening on the port you believe it is.  Try using netstat in this manner:

```
netstat -ano|Find ":2342"
```

You should see something like:

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:2342          0.0.0.0:0            LISTENING
```

Please comment on this post with the results of this command.

Answer (score 0):

The other source of the error could be a firewall. You should check your local configuration and consult with the network administrator as well.

Answer (score 0):

It would also help if you could show the firewall exception you have added.

Further to Kyle Smiths answer what is the app or service listening on port 2342 and how have you configured it to listen on 2342?